# load a div in jsp Using Spring render Url

Tags: java, jquery, spring, rendering

I am trying to load a div from another jsp say edit.jsp on a click event of button. According to the employee selected the page will be rendered with its id passed in the renderurl.

Using below , I am unable to get the div of edit.jsp in current jsp.

Any help. 
Thanks in advance.

```
@RenderMapping(params = "viewPage=editpayrollform")
    public String editpayrollform(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("empId::>>"+request.getParameter("employeeID"));
        String employeeID = ParamUtil.getString(request, "employeeID");
        request.setAttribute("employeeID", employeeID);
        return "editPayrollForm";


    }


<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="editUrl" >
    <portlet:param name="viewPage" value="editpayrollform" />
    <portlet:param name="employeeID" value="empIdSTR" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
```

```
<select class="form-control  select2me" name="<portlet:namespace/>employeeID" id="employeeID">

                                                    <option value="1">test1</option>
                                                    <option value="2">test2</option>
                                                    <option value="3">test3</option>
                                                    <option value="4">test4</option>
                                             </select>  
<button type="button" class="btn green" onclick="check();return false;">Go</button>
<div id="load">
</div>
</html>
<script>
function check() {
var editUrl1 = '<%=editUrl%>';
var employeeID  = $('#employeeID').val();
editUrl1 = editUrl1.replace("empIdSTR",employeeID);
$('#load').load(editUrl1).find('div#editforms'); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: This needs quite a lot more information. Can you at least start by describing what happens when you try it? Have you tried logging or debugging the code when it executes? What information do you get from that? Does the request to `editUrl1` hit the server, and does the server return a valid response?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave 
When I try calling the Url, it calls the method and returns the response and the whole page is displayed in it, whereas i just need div with id #editforms from that page to be displayed and not any other div. I've updated question with the method of controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation for .load() (http://api.jquery.com/load/), you don't want the .find() method, instead you want to do:

```
$('#load').load(editUrl1 + ' div#editForms')
```

I haven't tried this, but the second example in the documentation linked above (under the heading 'Loading page fragments') describes this, which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I have tried using this, bt it's  not working it is loading whole page not particular div

Comment: Can you update the code in your question with how you've changed it?

Comment: Its now working. :) thank you so much . Forgot to add space before div#editForms